# Why pathInfo shows null if is not null?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

The dd($request) shows a pathInfo `#pathInfo: "/nova-api/post-tags/20/update-fields"`. And I want to get that value, more specifically I want to check if "post-tags" is in the url.

However `dd($request->pathInfo);` shows:

```
null
```

But its not null as can be seen below:

```
Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest {#1703
  #container: Illuminate\Foundation\Application {#2
    #basePath: "/var/www/src"
    #hasBeenBootstrapped: true
    #booted: true
    ....
      "request" => Illuminate\Http\Request {#43
        ...
        #routeResolver: Closure() {#655
          class: "Illuminate\Routing\Router"
          ...
          }
          file: "/var/www/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php"
          line: "650 to 652"
        }
        +attributes: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#45
          #parameters: []
        }
        +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#51
          #parameters: array:5 [ …5]
        }
        +query: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#51}
        +server: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag {#47
          #parameters: array:63 [ …63]
        }
        +files: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag {#48
          #parameters: []
        }
        +cookies: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#46
          #parameters: array:4 [ …4]
        }
        +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag {#49
          #headers: array:21 [ …21]
          #cacheControl: array:1 [ …1]
        }
        #content: ""
        #languages: null
        #charsets: null
        #encodings: null
        #acceptableContentTypes: null
        #pathInfo: "/nova-api/post-tags/20/update-fields"
        #requestUri: "/nova-api/post-tags/20/update-fields?editing=true&editMode=update&viaResource=&viaResourceId=&viaRelationship="
        #baseUrl: ""
        #basePath: null
        #method: "GET"
        #format: null
        ...
      }
      ....
}
```

Do you know what can be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [API docs](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_path), you should be able to do:

`$request->path()`

to get the path info for the request.

Answer (score 3):

`$request->pathInfo` is a protected property in `symfony/http-foundation/Request.php`. You need to access it `$request->getPathInfo()`.